# Angular filter running more times than expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a filter to sort questions by category.

I am trying to figure out why my Angular filter is running more times than the input value.

**First issue:** The filter is run before questions are populated:

[image]

Then run again when there exists a question object:

[image]

**Second Issue:** My directive's `scope.questions` array only contains a single question object, yet the filter is running 6 times? Why is this?

Directive HTML snippet:

```
    <div class="category-filter">
        <div ng-repeat="(k, v) in catfilters" class="question">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-init="checked=true" ng-model="catfilters[k]">{{ k }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Loop:

```
    <div class="question-category">
        <li ng-repeat="q in questions | bycategory:catfilters" class="question">
            {{q.question.category.category}}
        </li>
    </div>
```

Directive JS: snippet

```
    scope.questions = args;

    console.log(scope.questions.length); //Length == 1
    /*
        Dynamically add question filters
     */
    scope.questions.forEach(function (k, v) {
        scope.catfilters[k.question.category.category] = true;
    });
```

Filter:

```
    filter('bycategory', function() {
        return function (questions, catfilterObj) {

            console.log('Q', questions); // Called 6 times

            var items = {
                categories: catfilterObj,
                out: []
            };

            angular.forEach(questions, function (value, key) {
                if (this.categories[value.question.cat_id] === true) {
                    this.out.push(value);
                }
            }, items);
            return items.out;
        };
    }
```

Comment: What you are seeing is the nature of how angular digests work. They run a minimum of 2 times until scope is stable and more if changes to scope are detected from within the digest.

Comment: @charlietfl is there a way to make this more efficient? 6 calls is pretty hardcore for an array containing a single object

Comment: Is it causing performance problems?

Comment: @charlietfl Not at this point, but when I scale it and multiple users are all taking tests, I do not want performance issues

Comment: The 6 times run on filter may not even be a result of the elements shown...it may have to do with other parts of the html being digested also.

Comment: @Growler Unless your multiple users are simultaneously using the same browser on the same machine, I don't see how the number of users would be a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @charlietfl points out, your angular expressions will continue to be called until the scope stabilizes.

This shouldn't be a concern unless you observe it to be causing performance problems, but if you are concerned, you could elminate some of the unnecessary operations in your filter:

```
filter('bycategory', function() {
    return function (questions, catfilterObj) {

        console.log('Q', questions); // Called 6 times

        return Array.prototype.filter.call(questions, function (value) {
            return catfilterObj[value.question.cat_id] === true;
        });
    };
})
```